# What is the default location for Redis AOF file for Ubuntu?

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04

### Background

Yesterday our machine crashed unexpectedly and our AOF file for Redis got corrupted.

Upon trying to start the service with `sudo systemctl start redis-server` we are greeted with the following logs:

> Bad file format reading the append only file: make a backup of your
>   AOF file, then use ./redis-check-aof --fix

### Research

Aparently this looks like a simple error to fix, just execute `./redis-check-aof --fix <filename>`.

Except I don't have the smallest idea of where that file is.

I have searched the Github discussions for this issue, but unfortunately none provides me with the location for the file:

- https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4931

The persistence documentation also doesn't make a mention of the location for this file:

- https://redis.io/topics/persistence

### Specs

These are the specs of the system where I am running Redis:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

### Question

Where is located this file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Find the configure file for Redis, normally, it's named `redis.conf`. The `dir` and `appendfilename` configuration specify the directory and file name of the `AOF` file.
2. Connect to Redis with `redis-cli`, and use the `CONFIG GET` command to get the `dir` configuration, i.e. `CONFIG GET dir`. The `AOF` file should located under this directory.

Answer (score 5):

The path is typically `/var/lib/redis/appendonly.aof` you will need to run `sudo redis-check-aof --fix /var/lib/redis/appendonly.aof`

Comment: cat: /var/lib/redis/appendonly.aof: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

in case if you use docker and append volume to /data then the path to appendonly.aof will be: /data/appendonly.aof

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using docker. I started the redis server without using `--appendonly yes`, then it started without any issues. And then ran `CONFIG GET dir` like @for-stack said and got this output:

```
1) "dir"
2) "/data"
```

So I checked under the /data path and found the file `appendonly.aof`

Then I ran `/usr/local/bin/redis-check-aof --fix /data/appendonly.aof` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `/path/redis-check-aof --fix /data/appendonly.aof` to fix this.
Thanks all.